# Python - Dataframe transpose and change structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, transpose

I want to transpose the df1 and "spread" each row's value into a few rows. At the same time instead of labeling data with column names I want to add the old column names into each row under a new column called "segment".

Here are the example that I have:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['index1', 'index2', 'index3'], 
              columns=["A", "B", "C"], 
              data=[[5,np.nan, "ok"], [7,8,"fine"], ["3rd",100,np.nan]])
df1
```

And I want the result look like the 2nd dataframe df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=["index1", "index1", "index1", "index2", "index2", "index2", "index3", "index3", "index3"], 
              columns=['segment', 'value'], 
              data=[["A",5], ["B",np.nan], ["C","ok"], ["A",7], ["B",8], ["C","fine"],["A","3rd"],["B",100],["C",np.nan]])
df2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [DataFrame.stack(dropna=False)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method:

```
In [102]: df1.stack(dropna=False) \
             .rename_axis(['index','segment']) \
             .reset_index(level=1, name='value')
Out[102]:
       segment value
index
index1       A     5
index1       B   NaN
index1       C    ok
index2       A     7
index2       B     8
index2       C  fine
index3       A   3rd
index3       B   100
index3       C   NaN
```